# Trying to code a Caesar cipher using python, problem:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've created this code and don't seem to understand where the problem is at; it only 'encrypts' one letter:

```
def c(word, offset):
    eword=""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in alphabet:
            index_letter= alphabet.index(letter)
            new_index= index_letter+offset
            if new_index>25:
                new_index= new_index-26
                eword+= aphabet[new_index]
            elif new_index<25:
                eword+= alphabet[new_index]
            else:
                eword.join(letter)
        return eword
```

when running the program

```
c("test", 3)
```

I get `'k'` only. could someone help me solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `return` is over-indented. It should be at the same level as `for` - now it's inside `for`, so it returns with the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` is inside the `for`-loop. This means you will always return `eword` after the first iteration. Try un-indenting it once:

```
def c(word, offset):
    eword=""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in alphabet:
            index_letter= alphabet.index(letter)
            new_index= index_letter+offset
            if new_index>25:
                new_index= new_index-26
                eword+= aphabet[new_index]
            elif new_index<25:
                eword+= alphabet[new_index]
            else:
                eword.join(letter)
    return eword  # <-- This line went back 4 spaces
```